Recognising the elements of the Grigorchuk group
The Grigorchuk group $\mathfrak{G}= \langle a,b,c,d \rangle$ is a group of automorphisms of the infinite rooted binary tree $\mathcal{T}_2$. Every element of $\mathfrak{G}$ can be represented by a finite rooted binary tree whose vertices are labelled by $1,a,b$, which records how the element under consideration acts on $\mathcal{T}_2$. Conversely, every labelled tree of this form defines an automorphism of $\mathcal{T}_2$, but which may not belong to $\mathfrak{G}$.

Is there a simple way to determine whether or not the automorphism of $\mathcal{T}_2$ given by a finite labelled rooted tree represents an element of $\mathfrak{G}$?

This is probably a well-known problem for specialists, so, if someone knows a good reference, I am interested!

I am not sure if such a description is known for the Grigorchuk group but there is a description along these lines for the closure of the Grigorchuk group in the automorphism group of the binary tree. https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0607778

The question you are asking is closely related to the representation of contracting regular branch groups (to which the Grigorchuk group belongs) by regular tree languages. It was introduced by Bartholdi and Noce in
arxiv.org/abs/2203.12963
However, they work with portraits of tree automorphisms, i.e. the full infinite (binary) trees where each vertex is annotated only with the permutation by which the automorphism acts on the vertices immediately below. For a contracting regular branch  group the set of the portraits of its Elements forms a regular tree language, i.e. a set of infinite trees accepted by a finite state tree automaton (think of a standard finite state automaton operating on an infinite word, but producing two successor states for each transition step and this way exploring all branches of the tree).
This gives an algorithmic answer to your question: Your description of a tree automorphism defines a tree automaton in a straightforward way, which accepts exactly one portrait (which is the automorphism you are describing). For regular tree languages, containment is a decidable property, i.e. it can be algorithmically checked if the language of your tree automaton is a subset of the language defined by the automaton describing the Grigorchuk Group. In other words, it can be algorithmically checked whether a tree automorphism in your description is contained in the Grigorchuk group (or any other regular contracting branch group for that matter).

I'll also add that the FR package in GAP might provide tools to practically check these things, however not in the language of (finite) trees, but by building an automaton first from your finite tree description. As I'm not experienced in using these tools though, I wont add it to my answer and leave it as a suggestion here.
